# Hide dropdown menu on click in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu similar to the one [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover). i need the same behaviour except that the `dropdown-content` class should hide when the user clicks on any of the item. I am looking for a possible CSS solution for this so that i don't have to write any JS for the same.

I tried different ways, but didn’t get the behaviour i needed due to the specificity. any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do in css only. You have to write js code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: none`. Or write it in JS like so:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown-content-id").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to what acharb07 said, simply add a script tag in your HTML doc. Though it isn't generally preferred to write your JS in your HTML, but in your case, it seems about right.
your code would be

```
<script>document.getElementById("dropdown-content-id").style.display = "none";</script>
```

simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way, though you can achieve what you want by the use of `focus-within` pseudo attribute.

just need to add the below style.

```
.dropdown-content:focus-within {
    display:none !important;
}
```

check below the updated example that you gave as an example.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content:focus-within {
    display:none !important;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the "*hide menu dropdown on click on wordpress css*" keywords this page is found in Bing.com, but the answers here aren't relevant, so I came up with the following that works in my case for Elementor's Hello theme, with JQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".menu-item").click(function() {
    $(".site-navigation-toggle-holder").removeClass("elementor-active");
  });
});
```